# Получить два значения в запросе mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

данным запросом получаю информацию о самом популярном товаре, но появилась необходимость получать не только информацию о самом популярном, но и о его профите(сколько он принес).

Получаю самый продаваемый товар таким образом

```
SELECT `item` 
FROM `purchase` 
GROUP BY `item` 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

В этой же таблице имеется колонка cost, хотелось бы получить информацию о сумме всех значений колонки cost, у которой `item` равняется полученному значению выше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное, так: `select item, sum(cost) as cost from purchase group by item order by count(*) desc limit 1;`

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, работает)